# Unity UI Broken and Altered on Devices with Notches

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

The Unity UI on physical devices with notches seems to be strangely altered, but, on an emulator with a notch (Pixel 3 XL), it works just fine. 
I have updated to Unity 2019.1.6, tried playing around with the settings and have  [implemented the safe area](http://The%20Unity%20UI%20on%20physical%20devices%20with%20notches%20seems%20to%20be%20strangely%20altered,%20but,%20on%20an%20emulator%20with%20a%20notch%20(Pixel%203%20XL),%20it%20works%20just%20fine.%20%20I%20have%20updated%20to%20Unity%202019.1.6,%20tried%20playing%20around%20with%20the%20settings,%20implemented%20the%20safe%20area).

Here's a screenshot comparing the altered UI (physical device) versus the intended UI (emulator):

[image: altered example]

[image: correct, intended screenshot]

All of my SDKS are up to date, with SDK 28 being the highest installed. I've tried using the SDK that comes with Unity as well as the SDK I have installed through Android Studio.

Here's the code for the Safe Area script (from the link above):

```
 using UnityEngine;

public class SafeArea : MonoBehaviour
{
    RectTransform Panel;
    Rect LastSafeArea = new Rect (0, 0, 0, 0);

    void Awake ()
    {
        Panel = GetComponent<RectTransform> ();
        Refresh ();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        Refresh ();
    }

    void Refresh ()
    {
        Rect safeArea = GetSafeArea ();

        if (safeArea != LastSafeArea)
            ApplySafeArea (safeArea);
    }

    Rect GetSafeArea ()
    {
        return Screen.safeArea;
    }

    void ApplySafeArea (Rect r)
    {
        LastSafeArea = r;

        // Convert safe area rectangle from absolute pixels to normalised anchor coordinates
        Vector2 anchorMin = r.position;
        Vector2 anchorMax = r.position + r.size;
        anchorMin.x /= Screen.width;
        anchorMin.y /= Screen.height;
        anchorMax.x /= Screen.width;
        anchorMax.y /= Screen.height;
        Panel.anchorMin = anchorMin;
        Panel.anchorMax = anchorMax;

        Debug.LogFormat ("New safe area applied to {0}: x={1}, y={2}, w={3}, h={4} on full extents w={5}, h={6}",
            name, r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height, Screen.width, Screen.height);
    }
}
```

The script is attached to a full screen panel and all of the UI elements are children of that panel.

Here are my player settings for Android:
[image]

[image]

Kinda find it weird that it works on an emulator but not on a physical device (not the physical device is an S8 while the emulator is a Pixel 3 XL).
From the incorrect screenshot, it seems it has something to either do with the notch or Android 9 Pie. Though the devices with notches also happen to be running Pie.